# exclude findAll result set

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to exclude certain results from a findAll in beautiful soup. I am trying to exclude the stylesheet links that have a media=print attribute

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://worldwildlife.org/"

request = urllib2.Request(url)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(request)

html = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
css_files = soup.findAll('link',{'rel':'stylesheet'})

print css_files
```

returns:

```
[<link href="/assets/application-b275a30a2c6726e3fabb10517f7cb812.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>, <link href="/assets/print-f0ba9e9b867691bb2fea40b2ab4e78d7.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>]
```

I have tried various ways and I am obviously new to python any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amend your search line to be:

```
css_files = soup.findAll('link',{'rel':'stylesheet', 'media': lambda L: L != 'print'})
# [<link href="/assets/application-b275a30a2c6726e3fabb10517f7cb812.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>]
```

Comment: Thanks - I obviously have some research to do on lambda. I have seen it quite a few times so it's about time I knew what it was! But thanks that worked a treat.

Comment: @user1683285 it creates a simple callable object. Since `bs4` allows callables as its selection criteria, the two work quite nicely together